# Why does this work, I am slicing 1 past max index and not getting an error?

Tags: go

I was playing around with slices, and I found something that I can't explain. I create a string of total length 10 (index ranges from 0 to 9) and then I create a slice from it specifying one past the max index and it does not panic. It will panic if I go more than one past the last index. What am I not understanding please?

I have investigated with integer slices as well thinking there might be something odd about strings, but it showed the same behavior.

Here is an example: I expected a failure at `x:= str[10:]`.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    var str = "attribute="

    x := str[10:]
    fmt.Printf("type of x is %T\n", x)
    //fmt.Printf("x is a %T and length of x is %d\n", x, len(x))

    for k, v := range []byte(str) {
        fmt.Printf("%d, %x\n", k, v)
    }

}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/Z-3YvTx3-s6

Output:

```
type of x is string
0, 61
1, 74
2, 74
3, 72
4, 69
5, 62
6, 75
7, 74
8, 65
9, 3d
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in [the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions). Having `low` or `high` equal to the length is allowed.

> For arrays or strings, the indices are in range if `0 <= low <= high <= len(a)`, otherwise they are out of range.

As to "why is this not an error": you can visualize the slicing operation as cutting *between* the elements. Like this:

```
│   a   t   t   r   i   b   u   t   e   =    │
│ ↑   ↑   ↑   ↑   ↑   ↑   ↑   ↑   ↑   ↑   ↑  │
│ 0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10 │
```

Technically slice point 10 is still within bounds, but it has no elements after it. That's why `[10:]` results in an empty string (that, or because there are no elements between `low` and `high`). This works the same way in ruby, for example. Maybe other languages too.

Answer (score 2):

From the language specification for [Slice expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions):

> For a string, array, pointer to array, or slice a, the primary expression
>
> ```
> a[low : high]
> ```
>
> constructs a substring or slice. The indices low and high select which elements of operand a appear in the result.
>
> .
>   .
>   .
>
> For arrays or strings, the indices are in range if 0 <= low <= high <= len(a), otherwise they are out of range. For slices, the upper index bound is the slice capacity cap(a) rather than the length.

So, both low and high **can** have the values `0` and `len(a)`.

Comment: Thanks Abdullah. Thas was unexpexted, but makes perfect sense.